# How to validate uniqueness of a field with a scope to enum value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, scope

I have a message table that have a enum field type_of_message[:private, :public] and belongs to a user, I want to validate that a user can only send only one public message.

`validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :type_of_comment[:review]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :type_of_message
```

If you just want to have validation for a particular type_of_message for example, I would suggest you write custom validation for it.

```
validate :one_public_comment_per_user, on: :create

private

def one_public_comment_per_user
  if user.present? && user.messages.public.present?
    errors.add(:base, "only one public comment is allowed per user.")
  end
end
```

Comment: This assumes that there's a field review on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by just passing review as a string instead of a symbol.
`validates_uniqueness_of :user, scope: :type_of_comment['review']`